# Get value from file in class mediator WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want my class mediator to get some values from a file that being processed by a proxy, how can i do this? 
My proxy is like this :

```
 <proxy name="Process"
      transports="vfs"
      startOnLoad="true"
      trace="disable">
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <class name="com.exec.GetValue"/>
     </inSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///Users/SourceFile</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///Users/Source</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.*</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
```

The scenario is like this, i put a files in the SourceFile folder, than i want the GetValue class to get some values from that file. Is there any way to do this? 

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

According to your proxy, you get the input from a file(since the transport is 'vfs'). So the class mediator message context contains the data you got from your input file.

You can get the SOAP body which contains the message, as follows,

SOAPBody body = synCtx.getEnvelope().getBody();